# how to work with big text in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, text

I am editing some  lists that I wrote before with `if` condition inside a loop  but if the text file is more than about **20 MB** it says *overflow*. and if more than **1 MB** it loads *for ever*. For example

```
string[] x = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);

string a = "";

for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    if (x[i].Length > 9 && x[i] < 13)
    {
        a += "" + x[i] + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

that is just an example if you know a topic that could help me please post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from changing `String` to `StringBuilder`:

```
string[] x = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//TODO: x[i] < 13 (taken from the question) seems to be erroneous
// Do you mean x[i].Length < 13?
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
  if (x[i].Length > 9 && x[i] < 13) 
    sb.AppendLine(x[i]);

string a = sb.ToString();
```

Next attempt can be *Linq*, something like this:

```
string a = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
  .ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
  .Where(line => line.Length > 9 && line.Length < 13));
```

When executing `a +=` you *recreate* `a` `string` (`string` is immutable class and can't be modified); recreating `string` in a *loop* can well appear to be *deadly slow*. `StringBuilder` is the class specially designed for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

you should use BufferedStream object to read/write larger file and it will also improve execution time.

```
   using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
   {
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       //write your logic here
    }
   }
```

Update :
go through link for fastest way to read file 
[Fastest way to read file](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files)

Comment: While a buffered stream can certainly make sense in a lot of situations (how much it helps in this specific case I don't know - disk based IO is already buffered), the main thing fixing his issue is that you read one line at the time. So I would recommend making that the focus of the reply.

Comment: @LarsMøllebjerg you are right. Here I have wrote working code for handle larger file.

Comment: i'm sure happy i asked i got two new ideas that made my life easier ^ ^